# Using case and arrays together in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, array, case

Is it possible to check if a variable is contained inside an array using `case`? I would like to do something like

```bash
ARR=( opt1 opt2 opt3 );

case $1 in
    $ARR)
        echo "Option is contained in the array";
    *)
        echo "Option is not contained in the array";
esac
```

Comment: Are you mandated to use `case`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test if an item is in a bash array?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177138/how-do-i-test-if-an-item-is-in-a-bash-array)

Comment: @muru, I'd say it's different here because of the `case` requirement. Presumably in the end the OP wants to  add more cases as in `case $1 in $ARR1)... $ARR2)... foo) bar)...; esac`

Answer (score 7):

With `ksh93`, thanks to [this bug](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/12), you can do:

```
IFS='|'
ARR=( opt1 opt2 opt3 )

IFS='|'
case $1 in
  (@("${ARR[*]}"))
    echo "Option is contained in the array";;
  (*)
    echo "Option is not contained in the array";;
esac
```

(I wouldn't rely on it as the bug might get fixed in the future).

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
case ${ARR[(Ie)$1]}
  (0)
    echo "Option is not contained in the array";;
  (*)
    echo "Option is contained in the array";;
esac
```

(though, you'd probably rather want to use `if (( $ARR[(Ie)$1] )); then echo is present...` here rather than a case construct).

`${array[(I)pattern]}` returns the index of the last element that matches the pattern in the array, or 0 otherwise. The `e` flag is for *exact* match (as opposed to *pattern* match).

With `bash`, `ksh`, `yash`, `zsh`, if you're ready to assume that `$ARR` and `$1` don't contain a certain character  like `@`, and that `$ARR` won't be empty, you can do:

```
IFS=@
case "@${ARR[*]}@" in
  (*"@$1@"*)
    echo "Option is contained in the array";;
  (*)
    echo "Option is not contained in the array";;
esac
```

With `bash -O extglob`, `zsh -o kshglob -o globsubst`, you could define a helper that builds a pattern based on the elements of the array:

```
arraypat() {
  awk '
    BEGIN{
      if (ARGC <= 1) print "!(*)"
      else {
        for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) {
          gsub(/[][|<>\\?*()]/, "[&]", ARGV[i])
          s = s sep ARGV[i]
          sep = "|"
        }
        print "@(" s ")"
      }
    }' "$@"
}

case $1 in
  ($(arraypat "${ARR[@]}"))
    echo "Option is contained in the array";;
  (*)
    echo "Option is not contained in the array";;
esac
```

Comment: I love the bash option and I'd really like you to explain the case with the IFS option. Would it also work without modifying the field separator?

Answer (score 3):

Not really in a compact and easy to use way.  Remember that `$ARR` will expand to only the first element of the array, `opt1` in your example.

You could use `"${ARR[@]}"`, but using your data this would give a false positive for the string `1 opt`.

With more recent versions of `bash`, you could consider using an associative array:

```
declare -A arr
arr=( [opt1]=1 [opt2]=1 [opt3]=1 )

if [[ "${arr[$1]}" -eq 1 ]]; then
   # $1 is a key in arr
else
   # is not
fi
```

Comment: Or to get full use of the associative array, i.e. use arbitrary values, not just `1`, test with something like `[[ "${arr[$1]+x}" ]]` (it's shorter, too!)

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, or `[[ -n "${arr[$1]}" ]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to do it with `case`? It's meant for string pattern matching, not per-element matching.

Frankly, if you need the "contains" test often and want to make it short because of that, just put the hard part in a function instead of using ugly workarounds:

```
#!/bin/bash
ARR=( foo bar doo );

contains() {
        typeset _x;
        typeset -n _A="$1"
        for _x in "${_A[@]}" ; do
                [ "$_x" = "$2" ] && return 0
        done
        return 1
}

if contains ARR "$1" ; then
        echo "\"$1\" is contained in ARR"
else
        echo "\"$1\" not contained in ARR"
fi
```

(That should also work in `ksh`)

Comment: OP probably wants a builtin for the presumed speed and efficiency.

Comment: @RonJohn, everything that function does, is built in to Bash. As for speed, it's hard to say, we'd need to test, but for huge data sets, associative arrays would probably be faster (than either the loop, or a `case`), since key lookups are presumably O(1). But for huge data, you shouldn't use the shell anyway, and for small data, minor performance differences don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

For `bash` users, you can use the non-short-circuiting `;;&` operator; it's not `case` directly supporting arrays in its clauses, but it's reasonably elegant:

```
ARR=( opt1 opt2 opt3 );

case $1 in
    *)
        [[ ${ARR[*]} =~ $1 ]] \
            && echo "Option is contained in the array" \
            && exit 0
        ;;&

    *)
        echo "Option is not contained in the array"
        ;;
esac
```

Note `;;&` (i.e. non-short circuiting) ensures the `$1` is evaluated against subsequent case-clauses; this requires the `exit 0` (use `return 0` in a function/sourced file) to skip subsequent