# while check if a variable is in an array bash

Tags: linux, bash, network-interface

I have a bug in my while loop check. I am checking if the user input is a valid user interface. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

net_array=()
for iface in $(ifconfig | cut -d ' ' -f1| tr ':' '\n' | awk NF)
do
        net_array+=("$iface")
done
unset "net_array[${#net_array[@]}-1]"

# Network Interface selection

printf "\nPlease select the network interface you want to use:\n"
read -r user_iface

while ! [[ "${net_array[@]}" =~ $user_iface ]]; do # check if the user input is valid
        echo "Please enter a valid network interface:"
        read -r user_iface
done
```

Generally this code works and checks if the element is in the array. My PC has eno1, eno2, eno3 interfaces and when I insert something different like eno5 it asks me again to insert the network interface.

The problem is that if I insert only `1`, it accepts it as a valid network interface, which is not the case and I want to exclude it. I guess I can perform additional check excluding all numerical user inputs, but I am wondering what my error is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regex match `[[ string =~ pattern ]]` doesn't actually match against the full string, but *searches* for the pattern in the string (like `grep`). You'd need to lock the pattern to the beginning and end of line, with the `^` and `$` special characters ("anchors").

So, you could do

```
[[ "$a" =~ ^"$b"$ ]]
```

quoting the variable so that its contents are not taken as a regex.

Though, since you only want to find full matches, why use a regex match at all, just compare for equality:

```
[[ "$a" = "$b" ]]
```

Except that of course your left hand side wasn't a single array item, but the whole array. Finding a matching in item an array with a pattern match like that is somewhat tricky, it was discussed here [Using case and arrays together in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/411001/170373) (in relation to `case`, but a pattern match anyway).

In brief, you could do something like this, searching for the chosen item with a space or start/end of string on both sides:

```
[[ "${net_array[*]}" =~ (^| )"$user_iface"( |$) ]]
```

It should work as long as the user doesn't enter any whitespace, though we could of course change `IFS` to get another separator.

---

But I would just loop over the array elements and check for a match:

```
found=0
for a in "${net_array[@]}" ; do
     [[ "$a" = "$user_iface" ]] && found=1
done
```

Or put the loop in a function:

```
contains() {
        typeset _x;
        typeset -n _A="$1"
        for _x in "${_A[@]}" ; do
                [ "$_x" = "$2" ] && return 0
        done
        return 1
}
```

and then the whole asking for input thing would something like this

```
while read -p "please enter a network interface: " -r user_iface; 
      ! contains net_array "$user_iface" ; do
    echo "$user_iface is not a valid interface!"
done
```

---

... or just use `select` and save the users some typing:

```
select choice in "${net_array[@]}" ; do 
    if [[ "$choice" ]]; then break; else echo "invalid choice!"; fi;
done;
echo "you chose $choice";
```

(it loops until you `break` out)