# How do I check whether a zsh array contains a given value?

Tags: zsh

Suppose I have a non-associative array that has been defined like

```
my_array=(foo bar baz)
```

How can I check whether the array contains a given string? I’d prefer a solution that can be used within the conditional of an `if` block (e.g. `if contains $my_array "something"; then ...`).

Comment: See also [How do I test if an item is in a bash array?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177138/how-do-i-test-if-an-item-is-in-a-bash-array) (it also has an answer about zsh)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
array=(foo bar baz foo)
pattern=f*
value=foo

if (($array[(I)$pattern])); then
  echo array contains at least one value that matches the pattern
fi

if (($array[(Ie)$value])); then
  echo value is amongst the values of the array
fi
```

`$array[(I)foo]` returns the index of the last occurrence of `foo` in `$array` and 0 if not found. The `e` flag is for it to be an `e`xact match instead of a pattern match.

To check the `$value` is among a *literal* list of values, you could pass that list of values to an anonymous function and look for the `$value` in `$@` in the body of the function:

```
if ()(( $@[(Ie)$value] )) foo bar baz and some more; then
  echo "It's one of those"
fi
```

To know how many times the value is found in the array, you could use the `${A:*B}` operator (elements of array `A` that are also in array `B`):

```
array=(foo bar baz foo)
value=foo
search=("$value")
(){print -r $# occurrence${2+s} of $value in array} "${(@)array:*search}"
```

Or using pattern matching on the array elements:

```
(){print -r $# occurrence${2+s} of $value in array} "${(M@)array:#$value}"
```

Comment: there is a closing brace missing in the first `if` (edit remains below the 6 character minimum …): `if ((${array[(I)$pattern]})); then`

Comment: @pseyfert, thanks. Fixed now. I opted for removing the `{...}` which makes it more legible. They are not necessary in zsh like in csh/rc/tcl/perl but unlike in ksh/bash/yash.

Comment: how to do it with an array literal? Trying if `(((a b c)[(I)$(./command | head -1)]))` leads to 'bad math expression' error.

Comment: @theonlygusti, see edit. Note that there's no such thing as *an array literal* in `zsh` (or any shell for that matters), only an array declaration syntax (`var=(some elements)` or `set -A var some elements` or `set var some elements` depending on the shell), and list of arguments passed to commands or to `for var in...`

Comment: The anonymous function is defined `()((body))`?

Comment: @Timo, more like `() body` where the body here is an arithmetic expression (`((...))`). It's similar to a normal function but with the function name omitted and can take arguments (not when the `body` is a simple command though), so `() { echo "$1"; } foo` or `() (echo "$1") foo` just like you'd do `f() (echo "$1"); f foo` in any POSIX shell, or `f() (($1 == $2)); f 1+1 2` in Korn-like shells.

Comment: ok, besides being anonymous it is called and defined at the same time. Seems like you can omit the curly braces to surround the body.

Comment: @Timo, it's similar to the *lambdas* of the `es` shell (as in `@ { echo $1 } foo` there)

Answer (score 30):

If you have an array `$my_array` and you want to know whether it contains the string `foo`, one possible test is

```
[[ ${my_array[(ie)foo]} -le ${#my_array} ]]
```

The full, exact value of the array element must be `foo`; it’s not a substring check or anything like that.

If you want to see whether the value of the variable `$my_string` is in the array, use

```
[[ ${my_array[(ie)$my_string]} -le ${#my_array} ]]
```

This `(ie)` syntax isn’t very obvious. It’s explained in [the Subscript Flags section](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Subscript-Flags) of the ZSH manual. The `i` part means that we are using “reverse subscripting”: instead of passing in a subscript and obtaining a value, like we do with the usual `${my_array[1]}`, we’re passing a value and asking for the first subscript that would give this value. This subscript is numerical and 1-based (the first element of the array is at index 1), which is different from the convention used by most programming languages. The `e` in `(ie)` means that we want an exact match, without expanding pattern-matching characters like `*`.

If the value is not found in the array, `${my_array[(ie)foo]` will evaluate to the first index *past the end* of the array, so for a 3-element array it would return 4. `${#my_array}` gives the index of the last element of the array, so if the former is less than or equal to the latter then the given value is present in the array somewhere. If you want to check whether a given value is *not* in the array then change the “less than or equal to” to a “greater than”:

```
[[ ${my_array[(ie)foo]} -gt ${#my_array} ]]
```

Comment: See also [Is there a reason why the first element of a Zsh array is indexed by 1 instead of 0?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/252368)