# count pattern matches in zsh array

Tags: zsh, array

I'm looking for something similar to the suggestion in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411331/150443):

Given a zsh array I want a count of how many elements match a pattern (rather than obtain the first/last match or the index of the first/last match, like the `rRiI` subscripting flags would do).

```bsh
myarray=(-test.list -test.v -c spam fiddle)

if ((${myarray[(I)-test.*]})); then
   echo "there is at least one test flag"
   echo "there are <solution here> test flags"
   if ((<solution here> >= 5)); then
      echo "seriously, there are many test flags"
   fi
fi
```

Ideally this should be possible to combine with slicing

```bsh
if ((${array[2,$end][(I)-test.*]})); then
   echo "there are <solution> test flag(s) in the range I consider interesting"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine three [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) features:

- `${…:#PATTERN}` to filter elements that match `PATTERN`;
- `(M)` to keep matching elements (without this flag, the filter removes matching elements);
- `${#…}` to count the resulting elements.

```
if [[ -n ${(M)myarray:#-test.*} ]]; then
   echo "there are ${(M)#myarray:#-test.*} test flags"
    …
```

And you can even combine this with subscripting.

```
% echo ${(M)#myarray[1,-1]:#-test*}
2
% echo ${(M)#myarray[2,-1]:#-test*}
1
```