# Bash - Looping through Array in Nested [FOR, WHILE, IF] statements

Tags: bash

I am trying to process a large file-set, appending specific lines into the "test_result.txt" file - I achieved it -not very elegantly- with the following code.

```
for i in *merged; do
        while read -r lo; do
                if [[ $lo == *"ID"* ]]; then
                echo $lo >> test_result.txt
                fi
                if [[ $lo == *"Instance"* ]]; then
                echo $lo >> test_result.txt
                fi
                if [[ $lo == *"NOT"* ]]; then
                echo $lo >> test_result.txt
                fi
                if [[ $lo == *"AI"* ]]; then
                echo $lo >> test_result.txt
                fi
                if [[ $lo == *"Sitting"* ]]; then
                echo $lo >> test_result.txt

        done < $i
done
```

However, I am trying to size-it-down using an array - which resulted in quite an unsuccessful attempt.

```
KEYWORDS=("ID" "Instance" "NOT" "AI" "Sitting" )
KEY_COUNT=0

for i in *merged; do
        while read -r lo; do
                if [[$lo == ${KEYWORDS[@]} ]]; then
                echo $lo >> ~/Desktop/test_result.txt && KEY_COUNT="`expr $KEY_COUNT + 1`"
                fi
        done < $i
done
```

Comment: How large is the file set? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/) that could be better accomplished by a straightforward `grep` command.

Comment: Small side note: Instead of ``KEY_COUNT="`expr $KEY_COUNT + 1`"`` you could also write `((KEY_COUNT++))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to get all the lines that contains at least one out of a set of words, from a set of files.

Assuming that you don't have *many thousands* of files, you could do that with a single `grep` command:

```
grep -wE '(ID|Instance|NOT|AI|Sitting)' ./*merged >outputfile
```

This would extract the lines matching any of the words listed in the pattern from the files whose names matches `*merged`.

The `-w` with `grep` ensures that the given strings are not matched as substrings (i.e. `NOT` will not be matched in `NOTICE`).  The `-E` option enables the alternation with `|` in the pattern.

Add the `-h` option to the command if you don't want the names of the files containing matching lines in the output.

If you do have many thousands of files, the above command may fail due to expanding to a too long command line.  In that case, you may want to do something like

```
for file in ./*merged; do
    grep -wE '(ID|Instance|NOT|AI|Sitting)' "$file"
done >outputfile
```

which would run the `grep` command once on each file, or,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*merged' \
    -exec grep -wE '(ID|Instance|NOT|AI|Sitting)' {} + >outputfile
```

which would do as few invocations of `grep` as possible with as many files as possible at once.

Related:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)

Comment: It is indeed a file-set of a few thousand. Originally, I built other processes into the loop but running grep separately - before the extra tweakings - it's a cleaner solution.  Just needed to add the "-h" option to suppress default prefixes - Thnks.

Comment: @AF.BJ since this answer solved your problem, consider accepting it: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Adding an array doesn't particularly help: you still would need to loop over the elements of the array (see [How do I test if an item is in a bash array?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177138/70524)):

```
while read -r lo; do
    for keyword in "${keywords[@]}"; do
        if [[ $lo == *$keyword* ]]; then
            echo $lo >> ~/Desktop/test_result.txt && KEY_COUNT="`expr $KEY_COUNT + 1`"
        fi
    done
done < "$i"
```

It might be better to use a `case` statement:

```
while read -r lo; do
    case $lo in
    *(ID|Instance|NOT|AI|Sitting)*)
        echo "$lo" >> ~/Desktop/test_result.txt && KEY_COUNT="`expr $KEY_COUNT + 1`"
        ;;
    esac
done < "$i"
```

(I assume you do further processing of these lines within the loop. If not, grep or awk could do this more efficiently.)