# User input to search bash array

Tags: bash, variable, array, variable-substitution

folks--

I'm getting kinda stuck, here. I have a small script that will be incorporated into a larger script. This small piece is supposed to take a user input, and compare it to a list of stored variables. If the user input matches one of the listed variables, it should output the string that is that variable; or, if it matches none of the elements, then it should write the user input to a new variable.

For context, what I've done is I've defined a few variables as strings (in this case, the citation information for textbooks). As an example:

```
books=()

buffa7="Wilson, Buffa, Lou. Physics. Pearson, 7th edition, 2009. ISBN: 0321601831"
books=+("$buffa7")

giancoli6="Giancoli, Douglas C. Physics: Principles with Applications. Prentice Hall, 6th edition. ISBN: 0321736990"
books=+("$giancoli6")
```

My understanding of this code is that it will make an array, `books`, and take the variables `$buffa7` and `$giancoli6` and append them to the list. What I'd like to do is prompt a user for input on the source: if they input `buffa7` or `giancoli6`, then the variable `$source` should be redefined to be the text assigned to the respective variable. If the user input does not match these, then the variable `$source` should be defined to be whatever the user input.

The problem I seem to be running into is that when the user inputs the source information, if they use `buffa7`, bash seems to think that if the actual string `buffa7` is not in its list, then it doesn't have to do anything, and thinks that `buffa7` is not in the list (which is true, because `$buffa7` is). Any advice on how to proceed would be much appreciated!

Comment: This can be done using name references or variable indirection, but what you should do is use associative arrays: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177589/70524

Comment: Thank you--another user said the same thing, too, and gave me a helpful example that illuminated just why/how things would work that way. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using name references or variable indirection, but what you should do is use associative arrays. There's no need for variables for each entry, when an associative array will do for the whole lot.

```
declare -A books
books[buffa7]="Wilson, Buffa, Lou. Physics. Pearson, 7th edition, 2009. ISBN: 0321601831"
books[giancoli6]="Giancoli, Douglas C. Physics: Principles with Applications. Prentice Hall, 6th edition. ISBN: 0321736990"
```

Then:

```
read input
source=${books[$input]}   # set $source to entry from array
if [[ -z $source ]]       # if $source is empty after that
then                      # $input was not in array, so
    source=$input         # set $source to $input.
fi
```

Comment: With bash 4.3 onwards you can test if an array element had been set with `[[ -v books[$input] ]]`. Otherwise you can check if it's unset with this construct `[[ -n ${books[$1]} || -z ${books[$1]-x} ]]`.

Comment: Got it- thanks very much! Being a new-ish to bash programming, I know just enough to know that stuff is possible, but not quite enough to know how to debug things that "should be simple" on their own. Thanks, once again!