# verify value of a variable being part of a list

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to make sure the value of a variable (`STATE`) is part of a list (`ALL_STATES`).

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

STATE='somevalue'
ALL_STATES=( lirum larum loeffelstiel )

echo state id is: "${STATE}"
echo all states are: "${ALL_STATES[@]}"

while ${STATE} not in ${ALL_STATES} ; do
      echo ${STATE} needs a valid value
      read -p "please provide the state ID: " STATE
done

echo state id is: "${STATE}"
```

I am getting `./test_while_loop.sh: line 8: somevalue: command not found` though. So there seems to be something wrong with my condition, just what?

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Related: [How do I test if an item is in a bash array?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177138)

Comment: Please read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

Comment: _Most_ of the shells' special variables are uppercase, but since zsh has one called `path`, one has to check their shell's manual anyway if they want to avoid clashing with names their shell holds special. The rest of the stuff about capitalization styles (e.g. `snake_case` vs. `CamelCase`) is just opinion-based...

Answer (score 0):

The error in your script is that in bash, the `while` keyword must be followed by a command, it does not interpret expressions. Also, `<value> in <array>` is not a valid expression either.

Instead you could turn the list into an associative array. Consider following the example given in this answer:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177589/573867